# Prefixed Columns are not allowed in PIVOT Operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My Query as below :

```
select * from 
   (
     SELECT ShoperCompCode, Name, Qty, Value, Tb, ASP, UPT, AST, CTS, class2cd, CashSaleQty FROM MBDSR 
   )A
PIVOT (AVG(CashSaleQty) FOR class2cd IN ("")) AS PVT
```

Tables as below :

```
ShoperCompCode  Name    Qty Value   Tb  ASP     UPT   AST    CTS    class2cd  CashSaleQty
 MB1            TEST    35  77064   6   2201.83 5.83  12844  0.44   Jeans    1
 MB2            TEST2   5   11095   2   2219    2.5   5547.5 0.06   T-shirt  2
 MB3            TEST3   0   0       0   0       0     0      0      Jeans    3
```

Now, i don't know the class2cd value wheather it will be "Jeans" or "T-shirt"

I.e (Class2Cd data is not static, it will be dynamic)..

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: MS SQL SERVER ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been resolved check my updated code.

```
  DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

  Select @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(Class2Cd) 
                from MBDSR
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

 set @query = 'SELECT * from 
         (
             SELECT ShoperCompCode, Name, Qty, Value, Tb, ASP, UPT, AST,       CTS, class2cd, CashSaleQty FROM MBDSR 
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            AVG(CashSaleQty) FOR class2cd IN (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

execute(@query);
```